# PrimeNG p-table doesn't show anything but the name of the table

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I've updatet PrimeNG from p-dataTable to p-table due to the upgrade of Angular to version 9.
I've a table users

```
users = ['one','two','three']
```

And I want to see them on the screen on rendering of the view, so I have a HTML

```
 <p-table [value]="users" [scrollable]="true"
                             scrollHeight="45vh">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="caption">Users</ng-template>
                        <div class="row" style="padding-left:80px">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="body">
                                <tr>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <!--ADD USERS-->
                                        <button type="button"
                                                class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-space center-block custom-font"
                                                (click)="popup.openModal(); popup.refreshTree()">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <!--REMOVE USERS-->
                                        <button type="button"
                                                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-space center-block custom-font"
                                                (click)="popup.deleteList(); popup.refreshTree(); clearIdsArray();">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </tr>
                            </ng-template>
                        </div>
                </p-table>
```

And then the [value] would be updated based on the action in popup mentioned in buttons.
The problem is I can not see any button on the screen and have no idea why. All I see is "Users" nothing more

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `div` which includes `<ng-template pTemplate="body">`

You can find basic example for templating [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v9.1.7-lts/#/table/basic).

Comment: Actually I've added this because I thouht it would help :P without it is the same, still no button on screen

Comment: Lol, I see! Can you add the screenshot of your table? I think you have buttons, but the content is empty for button, probably icons are not loaded for the buttons. You can try if the problem is this or not by adding some characters into the span inside of the button -> `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">TRY</span>`

Comment: Also you can try similar way like my previous example by changing icon class of span elements. For add button; `<span class="pi pi-plus"></span>` , for remove button; `<span class="pi pi-trash"></span>`

Comment: Actualy I've decided to implement it on my own, it's faster that way I suppose. Thanks for help :)